# Google Map marker not showing after uploading to server, locally works fine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a simple page that have google maps enabled, but I'm having an issue where my google maps marker is not showing after uploading the files to the hosting, it works fine locally.

I tried both using a custom marker and the default one, the issue is the same, it works locally but doesn't after uploading.

Here's the script I'm using

```
/*GOOGLE MAPS*/

function initialize() {

        // Declare map style
        var grayscale = [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":30},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]}];     

        var mapOptions = {
          center: {lat: 46.211000, lng: 16.913157},
          zoom: 13,
          scrollwheel: false

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        // Change map style
        map.setOptions({styles: grayscale});

        var image = 'img/vemo-google-map-marker.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: 46.211000, lng: 16.913157},
                map: map,
                title: "VEMO TRADE d.o.o.",
                icon: image,
        });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image]

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ju0uatnq/).  Did you upload the custom icon to the server in the correct place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specifiy whole absolute path here:

```
var image = '//YOUR_DOMAIN/img/vemo-google-map-marker.png';
```