# Google Map not showing after uploading to server, locally works fine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I'm trying to implement a simple page that have google maps enabled, but I'm having an issue where my google maps marker is not showing after uploading the files to the hosting, it works fine locally.

Here's the script I'm using

```js
var styles = [
    {
      "featureType":"landscape",
      "stylers":[
          {"saturation":-100},
          {"lightness":65},
          {"visibility":"on"}
          ]
        },
      {
        "featureType":"poi",
        "stylers":[
            {"saturation":-100},
            {"lightness":51},
            {"visibility":"simplified"}
            ]
          },
      {
        "featureType":"road.highway",
        "stylers":[
            {"saturation":-100},
            {"visibility":"simplified"}
            ]
          },
      {
        "featureType":"road.arterial",
        "stylers":[
            {"saturation":-100},
            {"lightness":30},
            {"visibility":"on"}
            ]
          },
      {
          "featureType":"road.local",
          "stylers":[
            {"saturation":-100},
            {"lightness":40},
            {"visibility":"on"}
            ]
          },
      {
          "featureType":"transit",
          "stylers":[
            {"saturation":-100},
            {"visibility":"simplified"}
            ]
          },
      {
          "featureType":"administrative.province",
          "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}
            ]
          },
      {
          "featureType":"water",
          "elementType":"labels",
          "stylers":[
            {"visibility":"on"},
            {"lightness":-25},
            {"saturation":-100}
            ]
          },
      { 
          "featureType":"water",
          "elementType":"geometry",
          "stylers":[
            {"hue":"#ffffff"},
            {"lightness":0},
            {"saturation":0}
            ]
          }
      ];

$("#my-map").gmap3({
    marker:{
      address: '96 New Moor St, Colombo'
    },
    map:{
      options:{
          styles: styles,
            zoom: 14,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        }
    }
});

// Show Map
$(".show-map").click(function(){ 
    if ($(".map").hasClass("opened")) {    
            $(".map").removeClass("opened");
            $(".show-map i").removeClass("fa-minus");
            $(".show-map span").text("Show Map");
        }
    else {   
            $(".map").addClass("opened");
            $(".show-map i").addClass("fa-minus");
            $(".show-map span").text("Hide Map");
        }
});
```

Comment: The snippet gives error !.

Comment: You may check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112570/google-map-marker-not-showing-after-uploading-to-server-locally-works-fine.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet gives error "$ is not defined" . I think you missed the JQuery import in your code , while uploading files to server, because that seems to be the issue.